# Strip quotes with JS to convert into JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Not sure how to address this with JavsScript to convert it into a json object to pull the below content, strip the first set of quotes so it becomes a valid JSON.

```
"{""title"": ""Glasses"",""desc"": ""Wood Custom Build""}"
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For starters what is the source of this string? Fixing it there would be the optimal solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything, here's a straightforward solution. Each string method is easily google-able if not clear.

```js
const string = `"{""title"": ""Glasses"",""desc"": ""Wood Custom Build""}"`
console.log(string)

// remove first and last
const spliced = string.substring(1, string.length-1)
console.log(spliced)

// replace double double quotes "" with single double quotes "
const replaced = spliced.replace(/""/gi, `"`)
console.log(replaced)

// parse as JSON
const json = JSON.parse(replaced)
console.log(json)
```

But to go into a bit more details, *it depends*! Based on the source of this string and what you need out of it, it might be useful to know that JSON keys *can* indeed have double-quotes `"` in their names. But the proper way to write it would be:

```
{ "\"yo\"": 42 }
```

If you DO need to keep the extra quotes (maybe because they are identifying strings that you have no hand over), then parsing this faulty JSON is more complicated because an opening quote `"\"` becomes different from a closing one `\""`.

```js
const string = `"{""title"": ""Glasses"",""desc"": ""Wood Custom Build""}"`

// remove first and last
const spliced = string.substring(1, string.length-1)
console.log(spliced)

// find pairs of double-quotes followed by (some optional space and) : or , or }
const closingQuote = /""(?=\s*[:,}])/g
const replaced_1 = spliced.replace(closingQuote, `\\""`)
console.log(replaced_1)

// find pairs of double-quotes that we haven't replaced yet
const notClosingQuote = /(?<!\\)""/g
const replaced_2 = replaced_1.replace(notClosingQuote, `"\\"`)
console.log(replaced_2)

const json = JSON.parse(replaced_2)
console.log(json)
```

This method uses regex's positive lookahead and negative lookbehind. IIRC they are somewhat new-ish features in the JS implementation of regex syntax.

Comment: Thanks @Sheraff appreciate it